# Ошибка при сборке проекта JavaFX в jar с помощью Maven

Tags: java, javafx, maven, jar, package

Пытаюсь разобрать в том как собрать JavaFX проект в jar при помощи Maven. Сделал, а вернее использовал готовый maven шаблон и на нем пытаюсь понять как собрать проект. Использую Java 11. Вот pom.xml файл который шел вместе с шаблоном. Зависимости модулей javaFx находятся в самом низу pom.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Lines</groupId>
    <artifactId>Tetris</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Tetris</name>
    <description>A simple version of JavaFX setup as described at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/enterprisefxpt3-1735081.html</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mainClass>Lines.MainApp</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <organization>
        <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
        <name>Your Organisation</name>
    </organization>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                            <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>

                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${java.home}/../bin/javafxpackager</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-createjar</argument>
                                <argument>-nocss2bin</argument>
                                <argument>-appclass</argument>
                                <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                                <argument>-srcdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}/classes</argument>
                                <argument>-outdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument>
                                <argument>-outfile</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>                            
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>
                            <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                            <commandlineArgs>${runfx.args}</commandlineArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

     </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalClasspathElements>
                        <additionalClasspathElement>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
                    </additionalClasspathElements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>sample.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- MigLayout -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.miglayout</groupId>
            <artifactId>miglayout-javafx</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

При сборке командой package выдает ошибку

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project Tetris: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /F:/Nikita/Documents/IdeaProjects/Tetris/src/main/java/module-info.java:[2,20] module not found: javafx.fxml
[ERROR] /F:/Nikita/Documents/IdeaProjects/Tetris/src/main/java/module-info.java:[3,20] module not found: javafx.graphics
[ERROR] /F:/Nikita/Documents/IdeaProjects/Tetris/src/main/java/module-info.java:[4,20] module not found: javafx.controls
[ERROR] /F:/Nikita/Documents/IdeaProjects/Tetris/src/main/java/module-info.java:[5,21] module not found: commons.lang
```

Как я понимаю у меня отсутствуют модули javaFx. Однако я их все прописал в module-info.java, они показываются в папке библиотек и приложение запускается (Показывается окно и так далее).
Вот module-info.java

```
module Tetris {
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires commons.lang;

    opens Lines;
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста сделать так чтоб проект собирался в исполняемый jar файл.

Comment: JavaFx выпелена в 11 версии, и не совместима на данный момент. Просмотрите билд зависимостей, возмно нужно будет в ручную генерировать для ним module-info. Советую отказаться от 9-11 версии до лучших времен - гемороя не оберетесь.

Comment: Попробуйте последние версии плагинов.

Comment: Если найдешь способ как собрать рабочую версию на 11 джаве - напиши. У меня ничего не вышло. Так или иначе необходимо добавлять аргументы к запуску jar, а при открытии файлчузера вообще приложение крашится с неизвестным исключением

Comment: Я написал решение, работает исправно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообщем я смог решить проблему следующим образом. Я модифицировал pom.xml следующим образом:
(Добавил classifier в depedencies и новый плагин maven-shade-plugin, другие плагины удалил.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Lines</groupId>
    <artifactId>Tetris</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Tetris</name>
    <description>A simple version of JavaFX setup as described at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/enterprisefxpt3-1735081.html</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mainClass>Lines.NewMain</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>Lines.NewMain</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>Lines.NewMain</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- MigLayout -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.miglayout</groupId>
            <artifactId>miglayout-javafx</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Проект собирается при помощи команды mvn package. 
Стоит отметить одну большую странность. Jar не запускался и выводил ошибку что у меня отсутствуют компоненты JavaFX. Проблемы почему то исходили из того что у меня главный класс наследовался из Application. Поэтому я создал новый класс NewMain с методом main(String[] Args) и из этого метода вызывал main моего исходного. 
Вот новый класс NewMain, его стоит указывать в pom.xml в качестве главного класса приложения

```
public class NewMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainApp.main(args);
    }
}
```

Вот уже исходный класс

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        String fxmlFile = "/fxml/hello.fxml";
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent rootNode = loader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream(fxmlFile));
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootNode, 400, 200);
        stage.setTitle("Hello JavaFX and Maven");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: И что, запускается без дополнительных аргументов и по двойному щелчку?

Comment: Да, все работает как надо. У меня во всяком случае

Comment: Надо будет попробовать